Linear relaxation infeasible in PuLP
I am modelling to optimal behaviour of a household battery. The buying price from the grid is different than the selling price to the grid (buying price is always higher). How do I model this correctly? Currently, I keep running into the problem that the linear relaxation is infeasible.
`import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pulp import LpMaximize, LpProblem, LpVariable, lpSum, LpBinary

# Constants
BATTERY_CAPACITY = 5  # kWh
BATTERY_EFFICIENCY = 0.9  # %
MAX_CHARGE_RATE = 1  # kW
MAX_DISCHARGE_RATE = 1  # kW
HOURS_IN_YEAR = 24 * 365
HOURS_IN_DAY = 24
YEARLY_USE = 5700
YEARLY_PV_GEN = 0

# Read data from CSV file
data = pd.read_csv('DynamicPriceInput.csv', sep=';', decimal=',')

# Adjust hourly values by yearly totals
data['pv_generation'] *= YEARLY_PV_GEN
data['household_load'] *= YEARLY_USE

# Initialize the linear programming problem
prob = LpProblem("Battery_Optimization", LpMaximize)

# Decision variables for charging/discharging rates
charge_discharge = LpVariable.dicts("charge_discharge", range(HOURS_IN_YEAR), -MAX_DISCHARGE_RATE, MAX_CHARGE_RATE)
soc = LpVariable.dicts("soc", range(HOURS_IN_YEAR), 0, BATTERY_CAPACITY)

# Auxiliary variables for buying and selling
buy_from_grid = LpVariable.dicts("buy_from_grid", range(HOURS_IN_YEAR), lowBound=0)
sell_to_grid = LpVariable.dicts("sell_to_grid", range(HOURS_IN_YEAR), lowBound=0)

for t in range(HOURS_IN_YEAR):
    # Net grid load is the difference between household load, PV generation, and battery charge/discharge
    net_load = data['household_load'][t] - data['pv_generation'][t] + charge_discharge[t]
    
    # Enforce the constraint that the net load is either bought or sold from/to the grid
    prob += net_load == buy_from_grid[t] - sell_to_grid[t]
    

# Objective function to minimize net cost (buy from grid minus sell to grid)
prob += lpSum([
    buy_from_grid[t] * data['buy_price'][t] - sell_to_grid[t] * data['sell_price'][t]
    for t in range(HOURS_IN_YEAR)
])

# Constraints
for t in range(1, HOURS_IN_YEAR):
    prob += soc[t] == soc[t-1] + (charge_discharge[t] * BATTERY_EFFICIENCY)
    prob += soc[t] >= 0  # SOC cannot be negative
    prob += soc[t] <= BATTERY_CAPACITY  # SOC cannot exceed battery capacity

# Solve the problem
prob.solve()`


I'm betting the issue is lack of curtailment in your model.  By using equality constraints, over the course of the year, if you have excess PV input for instance, it has nowhere to go once the battery is at full SOC.

This is not reproducible unless you provide the contents (at least a subset, if the contents are large) of your CSV.
